# Python - get data from server (ajax) - 'str' object is not callable error

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I think I've looked almost all the examples in google to solve the issue, but still can't get it working well.

*My goal* is to request data from server after clicking on a button. 
*The error* I get at this moment:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1546, in __call__
    return response(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
INFO     2015-01-04 22:16:52,235 module.py:709] default: "POST /nearest_banks/radius HTTP/1.1" 500 662
```

**My code:**

***ajax function:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#yes" ).click(function() {
        $( "#ask_user" ).hide();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '/nearest_banks/radius',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
           // data: { 'names': {{names}}, 'location': {{location}} },
            success: function (output) {
                output = JSON.parse(output);
                ("#places").empty();
                output.forEach(function (names) {
                    var $row = $('<p>').appendTo("#places");
                });
            }});
    });
</script>
```

***Python function:***

```
def post(self):
        names, location, telephone, check = funcs.Findplaces(default_radius)  
        dict = {'names': names, 'location': location}
        output = json.dumps(dict)
        return output
```

- function *Findplaces* works well. It returns names, location etc the right way in Unicode type.

***These are my urls:***

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
   webapp2.Route(r'/', handler=MainPage, name='mpage', handler_method='get'),
   webapp2.Route(r'/nearest_banks', handler=Nearest_banks, name='ne_banks', handler_method='main_func'),
   #webapp2.Route(r'/nearest_banks/radius', handler=Nearest_banks, name='ne_banks', handler_method='get'),
   webapp2.Route(r'/nearest_banks/radius', handler=Nearest_banks, name='radius', handler_method='post'),
], config=session_module.config, debug=True)
```

As I understand the error is in the Python *def post* function .. **Please, help me someone to cope with it ...**

All I need is to get data from server and show it in some tag on page...

Comment: You must avoid using keywords like dict as variable names, as these override the in-built objects and giving rise to many problems,I don't guess you are facing same issues over here, But just for the sake of good programming practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html#returned-values

> A handler method doesn't need to return anything: it can simply write to the response object using `self.response.write()`.
>
> But a handler can return values to be used in the response. Using the default dispatcher implementation, if a handler returns anything that is not None it **must** be a `webapp2.Response` instance. If it does so, that response object is used instead of the default one.

Your `post()` handler is now returning a string.